# CSS is DIFFERENT in some Android browsers than it is in desktop browsers

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a CSS-only slideshow on my Android phone. The slideshow works fine in Firefox for Android but doesn't work properly in Chrome, Brave or Samsung Internet. My phone is a Samsung A5 (2017) and my laptop is running Windows 10.

When I connect my phone to my laptop and look at the Chrome browser from my phone in Chrome Devtools via USB Debugging, I'm noticing some odd things in the CSS as rendered on the phone. The source code of the SaSS has the max-width of an element called #slideshow hard-coded as 410px:

```
#slideshow {
  max-width: 410px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The precompiled CSS file is identical. However, when I look at the same block of code in Chrome on the phone, max-width is 407px, even though I uploaded it and was careful to ensure that it did upload successfully. I was also careful to reload the page in Chrome (for Android).

```
#slideshow {
  max-width: 407px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }
```

I even deleted the css file on the server and re-uploaded it from my laptop but the max-width still shows up as 407px. This is part of the problem because each of the images in the slideshow has a width of 408px; the max-width of #slideshow has to be greater than or equal to 408px.

But that's not the end of the weirdness. Now we get to the SaSS (mis-)calculations. I have a variable called $number_of_slides which I set to 12. Then I calculate two things. For #slides .inner, I calculate a width as 100% times the number of slides:

```
#slides .inner {
  @debug 100 * $number_of_slides;
  width: 100% * $number_of_slides;
  line-height: 0
}
```

With $number_of_slides set to 12, the width for #slides .inner should obviously be 1200% and that's exactly what the css file shows:

```
#slides .inner {
  width: 1200%;
  line-height: 0; }
```

The precompiler also shows a value of 1200% from the @debug statement.

But when I look at the CSS that's been rendered on the phone via Chrome DevTools, the width for #slides .inner shows a width of 1100%!

```
#slides .inner {
  width: 1100%;
  line-height: 0; }
```

The other calculation that uses $number_of_slides is this one:

```
#slides article {
  @debug 100 / $number_of_slides;
  width: 100% / $number_of_slides; 
  float: left
}
```

The CSS file shows that the precompiler has done the right thing:

```
#slides article {
  width: 8.3333333333%;
  float: left; }
```

The @debug statement confirms that the width is being correctly calculated as 8.333333333% by the precompiler.

However, when I look at that same selector in the CSS on the phone, I get this:

```
#slides article {
  width: 9.0909090909%;
  float: left; }
```

I am completely baffled. I can't think of any mechanism that would explain this odd behaviour. A hard-coded value and two calculated values are DIFFERENT between Chrome on my phone and Chrome on my laptop for no obvious reason even though there is just a single version of the file being used by both browsers.

When I manually edit the CSS file on my phone, the slideshow renders much better in Chrome although not yet perfectly, so there are probably additional alterations to the CSS file that I haven't noticed yet.

Can anyone suggest WHY the CSS file on my phone is different from the CSS file on my laptop? If I can keep it from changing, perhaps I can solve the whole problem in one go.

I'm using a current version of FileZilla to do my uploads.